# Server side javascript on Google app engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, server-side, serverside-javascript

Is there any way to run a Javascript engine, like Spidermonkey, on Google App Engine?  Spidermonkey is a C module, so obviously that wont work (GAE doesn't allow those types of modules)... is there something else available?

Comment: The people who answered here seem to have a great deal of expertise. I have a very very simple problem. Might you guys help me with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192485/using-rhino-instead-of-scriptengine-to-run-javascript-code-in-java I just need to get a Date from JavaScript to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is now supporting custom language on Google App Engine. So we can do Node.js

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8jZHc0NS6A

https://developers.google.com/cloud/managed-vms

Answer (score 8):

[Here is an article](http://www.nanaze.com/2009/04/javascript-on-rhino-on-java-on-app.html) about running Rhino on AppEngine/Java. That should get you a long way towards a real, functioning JavaScript application on AppEngine.

Comment: cool... thanks!  my app is in Python... but seems like there are some options to run both at same time

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a JavaScript framework (as opposed to calling Java methods from JavaScript) you could try [RingoJS](http://ringojs.org/wiki/) (formerly  Helma NG). It's a Rhino-based JavaScript framework that can run in AppEngine.

There's also AppengineJS, which can run on RingoJS (or [Narwhal](http://www.narwhaljs.org/), which I haven't personally used). It's a port of the Python SDK (with mostly predictable changes to fit JavaScript conventions better). It's not complete, but it's close enough to work in most cases. It's nicer to use than using the Java API directly.

Comment: Thanks for posting that; I've been trying to remember the name for a week!!

Comment: thanks... I saw "Helma NG" listed in the comments of Adam's link... but couldn't actually find the project.

Comment: looks like AppengineJS.org is defunct.

Answer (score 3):

I've also built [ApeJS](https://github.com/lmatteis/apejs) if you want to try it out. It's much more minimal than the competition.