# Using Rhino instead of ScriptEngine to run Javascript code in Java

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, rhino, scriptengine

Based on the discussion [converting string representation of unknown date-format to Date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134422/converting-string-representation-of-unknown-date-format-to-date-in-java), I want to use the JavaScript `Date` function in my App-Engine project. However, ScriptEngine does not work on App-Engine. So I need a little help converting to Rhino. Here is the ScriptEngine code I need to convert:

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String script = "var date = new Date('" + dateInUnknownFormat + "'); var timestamp = date.getTime();";
engine.eval(script);
long timestamp = ((Double) engine.get("timestamp")).longValue();
```

The following has not worked

```
private static long parseDateUsingRhino(String dateInUnknownFormat){
    Context mozillaJsContext = Context.enter();
    Scriptable scope = mozillaJsContext.initStandardObjects();
    String script = "var date = new Date('" + dateInUnknownFormat + "'); var timestamp = date.getTime();";
    Object obj = mozillaJsContext.evaluateString( scope, script, "TestScript", 1, null );
    Double timeDouble = Double.parseDouble((String) obj);
    long timestamp = timeDouble.longValue();
    return  timestamp;
}
```

and I have already replaced `"TestScript"` with `null` and `""`.

Comment: Did you forget to add the error trace?

Comment: No. I took it out because it was irrelevant. I just don't know how to write the code correctly. The irrelevance is due to that I get different errors or no errors depending on what I try. But in the end, I can never get Rhino to produce a result. Clearly someone who knows how Rhino works, will have no problem translating the ScriptEngine version to Rhino.

Answer (score 1):

In the script that is executed by the JavaScript engine, you just need to calculate the value you want using `new Date(dateString).getTime()` (you could also use `"var date = new Date(dateString); date.getTime()";`). You should not store the result inside a variable.

I also made two additions to your method:

- To convert the result of the evaluation to a String, you should use `Context.toString(obj)`. Since here, the result is actually a number, we can use directly `Context.toNumber(obj)`, which returns a `double`, and cast it to `long`.
- I added a `finally` block which exits from the `Context`.

Working code:

```
private static long parseDateUsingRhino(String dateInUnknownFormat) {
    Context mozillaJsContext = Context.enter();
    try {
        Scriptable scope = mozillaJsContext.initStandardObjects();
        String script = "new Date('" + dateInUnknownFormat + "').getTime()";
        Object obj = mozillaJsContext.evaluateString(scope, script, "TestScript", 1, null);
        return (long) Context.toNumber(obj);
    } finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
System.out.println(parseDateUsingRhino("2015-10-25T15:06:42.000Z")); // prints 1445785602000
```

Side note: this was tested with Rhino 1.7.7.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it first like this and see if it works:

```
private static long parseDateUsingRhino(String dateInUnknownFormat){
        Context mozillaJsContext = Context.enter();
        Scriptable scope = mozillaJsContext.initStandardObjects();
        String script = "var date = new Date().getTime();";
        Object result = mozillaJsContext.evaluateString( scope, script, "", 1, null );
        return Long.valueOf(Context.toString(result));
    }
```

And according to [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0640.html) all you need to do next is pass the `dateInUnknownFormat` variable like so, no java string concatenation required (the context is smart enough to probably consider the java method's accessible variables as global variables in the javascript scope):

`String script = "var date = new Date(dateInUnknownFormat).getTime();";`

Comment: I am having a similar problem and so I try to apply your solution and I get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"`. And that's with your exact code block that has `"var date = new Date().getTime();"`

Comment: did you test this code before posting? It does not work.